# Replacing a row in ngGrid with JavaScript 'splice' method - angularjs, nggrid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to replace an item in ngGrid with a different item. Splicing a single item works. Using splice to insert an item:

```
$scope.myData.splice(1, 0, object);
```

also works. However, splice(index,1,object) does not update grid. How can I show updates to myData on ngGrid? I have replicated the problem [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JwGzBWrOabFO00VdWnTT?p=preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should work, I'd report it as a bug to the `ng-grid` team.  If I change `$watch` to `$watchCollection` in their source it works fine (lines 3295, 3296 in `ng-grid.js`) ([***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/VErqWb5FIzpBQCZOIH8L?p=preview)):

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', $scope.$parent.$watchCollection(options.data, dataWatcher));
$scope.$on('$destroy', $scope.$parent.$watchCollection(options.data + '.length', function() {
```

As an alternative you could use angular.copy to change the properties on the existing object instead of splicing the new object in:

```
angular.copy(obj, $scope.myData[1]);
```

Comment: It's not only with that line of code, either. If I try to splice, then push, the grid doesn't update - seems like more than one action will cause this. I did manage to come up with a workaround, though it is a bit longer than I'd prefer..

Comment: There's been a response, seems like the current version of ngGrid is not doing a deep watch. This will be fixed in v3. Guess I'll keep my workaround until v3 is officially released. Going to go ahead and give your answer a check, thanks for your help @Jason!